# Як українською буде вчительська "указка"?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

[СУМ подає таке:](http://sum.in.ua/s/ukazka)

> 1. Довга паличка, якою що-небудь показують, указують. *Водячи указкою по карті, він розповідає, які ріки зустрінуться під час мандрівки* (Олесь Донченко, IV, 1957, 383); *Гетьманова рука твердо провела срібною указкою рису від Вінниці до Умані* (Натан Рибак, Переяславська Рада, 1953, 323).

Але приклади вжитку доволі нові, чи є інші варіанти?

Comment: Чи знаьете, коли зо̂ьавила сьа *указка*? Но і ьак алтернатіва: *указник* і *укажчик*.

Comment: @stegetsj на жаль, не знаю коли. Можу припустити, що з першими сучасними школами чи географічними товариствами, може й сотні років тому.

Comment: @stegetsj хіба *-жчик* це українське словотворення?

Comment: Но, наросток *-чик* — так, так само *-ьчик* проти *-ник*. Правда, о̂н переважно дльа живого: *хлопчик*, *пальчик*, *заьчик*, *зубчик*, *докажчик*, *покажчик* (проти *показник*, котре маье гинше значеннє) ітд. Не можу ручати сьа на 100 %, але поки схоже на Украьинське.

Comment: @stegetsj я бачив [таку думку](https://r2u.org.ua/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3466): *Тобто слова на -чик [без ознаки здрібнілості] в нас одиничні, на кшталт: небіжчик – полонізм, є варіянт небіжник і поширеніше слово покійник; братчик — тут, можливо, якраз здрібніла форма. Власне, усім словам з -чик, які не вписуються в українські норми творення [варваризмам], є в українській заміна, зокрема таким поширеним росіянізмам, як льотчик, датчик, покажчик. Деколи така заміна незвична.*

Comment: Ага, бачу, тобто _чик_ переважно дльа означенньа здро̂бнилостьи; згадані мноьу _хлопчик_, _пальчик_, _зубчик_, _заьчик_ по̂дпадаьуть по̂д це. Тож така думка маье по̂дґрунтьа.

Answer (score -1):

Можливо, "вказівниця", якщо таке слово є.

Comment: Вітаю Вас на сайті. _Вказіниця_ — це дуже цікавий варіант. Але в нашій спільноті склалася така традиція, що відповіді обґрунтовують, а не просто наводять ідеї. Наприклад, можна навести словники, які пропонують це слово, або приклади літератури, де воно вживається.

Comment: От, наприклад, що я знайшов у Google Books: [«Тим часов Горлов підійшов до картини, в руках його була довга вказівниця»](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=9FznAAAAMAAJ&q=вказівниця) в пригодницькому романі Івана Власенка (1987) і [згадка](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=sbHqAAAAMAAJ&q=вказівниця) в книжці «Українська лексика кінця двадцятого століття». Це варто було б добати у відповіль, щоб зробити її [доброю](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/). Також, для чесності, варто було б зазначити, що слово вживають доволі рідко й словники його поки не наводять.

Comment: Дякую! А як же тоді словники пропонують перекладати "указку"?

Comment: Сучасні українські словники, наслідуючи радянські, вважають, що в українській мові є слово _указка_ (наприклад, [1](http://sum.in.ua/s/ukazka), [2](https://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/)) і, відповідно, що російське _указка_ перекладається українським _указка_. Можна, звісно, стояти на позиції, мовляв, це не притаманне українській мові слово, а результат зросійщення, і словники варто виправляти (така позиція, по-моєму, цілком доречна, якщо її обґрунтувати — чому саме Ви вважаєте це слово непритаманним українській мові). Але поки що, наскільки я можу судити, словники саме за _указку_ :-/.